# How do I debug the inner workings of QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt

If I have a `QTableView` and I want to step through the code that gets executed when I click a column header, how would I do that? Where should I be putting my breakpoint to see inside of the inner workings of `QTableView`? For example, I know that clicking a column header in the table will sort the column when sorting is enabled. But how do I see this happen and actually step through the code for `QTableView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you're looking for is `QHeaderView`. You can begin by setting a breakpoint in `void QHeaderView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)`.

Comment: Thank you, Kuba. This is most likely a dumb question, but to set the breakpoint, do I first define 'void QHeaderView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)' in my header file and then input my logic in the cpp file?

Comment: @orbit Not at all. That method already exists! I gave you a signature of a method you need to set a breakpoint on. You may wish to consult the documentation of your debugger on how to do that. E.g. in gdb (e.g. via Qt Creator's debugger console) you'd write `break QHeaderView::mousePressEvent`. In cdb you'd do something like `bp @@(QHeaderView::mousePressEvent)`

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I will have to do some more research on debugging correctly. You have helped point me in the right direction.